# Customise FSCalendar in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, fscalendar

[image]

I need to achieve the design in calendar , there will be maximum of 5 colours will come for a date , I got one colour as border method in fscalendar ,  but not able to add multiple colours. Please help to resolve this, if anyone have any other suggestion please guide me,

Thanks in advance

Comment: The image you have added, is it the design you are trying to achieve?

Comment: yes,I need to achieve the above one